# An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: kunte 0Reputation points

Tags: php, sql-server, macos

Am using macOs and using docker to run microsoft sql server the connection with the server is well established but when am trying to run migration i get errors

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations migrations:migrate

In ExceptionConverter.php line 67:

An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling stat(/usr/local/

etc/openssl@3/certs)][error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling stat(/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs)]

In Exception.php line 28:

SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling stat(/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs)][error:80000002:

system library::No such file or directory:calling stat(/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs)]

In Driver.php line 47:

SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling stat(/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs)][error:80000002:

system library::No such file or directory:calling stat(/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs)]

migrations:migrate [--write-sql [WRITE-SQL]] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--all-or-nothing [ALL-OR-NOTHING]] [--configuration CONFIGURATION] [--em EM] [--conn CONN] [--db-configuration DB-CONFIGURATION] [--] [<version>]
```

I have located the file its exist here. /usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs
Also i have tried to pass the path like this
`sqlsrv:Server=(local);Database=DBNAME;Certificate=/usr/local/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem`

Am trying to run migrations

Comment: Cross posted from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1625782/an-exception-occurred-in-the-driver-sqlstate(08001)).

Comment: You're likely experiencing this issue because SQL Server installs use a self-signed certificate by default. I believe that the [Server]`Certificate=...` connection string option is meant to point the public key of the certificate you've exported from the target server. Have you tried to export the certificate from the SQL Server container yet? Ref: [ServerCertificate option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute#servercertificate)

Comment: The OP didn't even try to hide it, @AlwaysLearning , due to the "kunte 0Reputation points" in the title. Just copy pastad away.